# passing 2D array to RPC using C

Tags: c, rpc

I want to build matrix multiplication using RPC in C. Shall I pass element one by one via client terminal, or there is other efficient ways? What is the best way to pass the two matrices to the server?

Answer (score 0):

No doubt, passing elements one by one will be the most inefficient way.  It would require the sending communication stack to frame each element with the appropriate packet headers; as well as the receiving communication stack to parse the headers to retrieve each element.

You might consider passing a row at a time.

The most efficient would be to send the entire 2D array as a single object.

Comment: Thanks a lot!- Yes ,I formulated my matrixes and send them as an object ,and 1 D array from the client - In the server side convert it to 2D and did multiplication ,then return it back as a 1D result ...Though I follow  logical steps , I don't know why I don't receive a correct answer! ... Do you have any idea how to debug RPC program?